# ZSH and Passwordless access with SSH in a shared home environment

Tags: linux, ssh, zsh, cluster

I have a small cluster with some nodes which share their home folder through NFS. I allow passwordless SSH access to the users with this script:

```
if [[ -e $homeDirs/$username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ]]; then
    echo "User '$username' already has a public key"
else
    su $username -c "ssh-keygen -N ''"  
fi

cat $homeDirs/$username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $homeDirs/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown $username:$username $homeDirs/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 $homeDirs/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This has been working properly so far, but now I would like to use **zsh** shell instead of bash, and it doesn't work anymore. Any clues?

Thanks!!

Comment: As far as I can see, this code should work just fine with `zsh`. What are the error messages, if any? How are `username` and `homeDirs` set?

Comment: No error messages, I just get asked for the password. username and homeDisr are set properly also. I think I know what's going on. I don't have installed zsh in the rest of the nodes... could that be the problem?

Comment: yes it was that... sorry, I fogot to check that...! :-/
Thanks!